# RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (5x46656 and 50176x3)

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build a cnn model and while building i am getting the run time error. I have image size of 224x224x3 and batch size of 5 and i have 3 classes to be predicted.

```
class CNN(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    #5*3*224*224
    self.conv1=nn.Conv2d(3,6,3,1)
    self.relu1=nn.ReLU()
    self.pool=nn.MaxPool2d(2)
    #112*112*6

    self.conv2=nn.Conv2d(6,16,3,1)
    self.relu2=nn.ReLU()

    self.fc1=nn.Linear(16*56*56,3)

def forward(self,x):
    x=self.pool(self.relu1(self.conv1(x)))
    x=self.pool(self.relu2(self.conv2(x)))
    x=x.flatten(1)
    x=self.fc1(x)
    return x
```

I get the run time error during training. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the size of your input, your fully connected layer should have `16*54*54` neurons, not `16*56*56`.

```
self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16*54*54, 3)
```

Alternatively, you can you a lazy module that will infer the number of neurons needed: [`nn.LazyLinear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LazyLinear.html):

```
self.fc1 = nn.LazyLinear(3)
```

Comment: How it 16*54*54?. I am using (w-f+2p/s)+1 formula and i am getting 16*56*56. Can you tell me where i am doing wrong?

Comment: I think you are looking to apply a padding of `1` to compensate the 3x3 conv. Instead, what you've provided (as the 4th (optional) positional argument of `nn.Conv2(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride)` is the stride. A bit of general advice, consider using kwargs to avoid these traps, e.g. `self.conv1=nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 3, padding=1)`.